# Write and Read in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Realtime database with the below rules

```
{
    "rules": {
      "users": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
         }
       }
    }
}
```

My code to write in database is

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("OWNER_DATA");
String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();
            OwnerSignup ownerSignup = new OwnerSignup(id, name, email, phoneNumber);
            mDatabase.child("MY_DATA").setValue(ownerSignup);
```

If I change the rules to

```
read:"false" 
write:"false"
```

I can push the data but with the above rules I cannot insert values in the data.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

and how can I call this with API in Postman where my API is 
"https://rent-c-246c0.firebaseio.com/"

I tried to do this in postman with the below given API
https://rent-c-246c0.firebaseio.com/OWNER_DATA.json

here I want to pass my auth.uid token

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following rules:

```
read:"false" and write:"false"
```

It means you cannot retrieve nor add data to the database.

If you use:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "request.auth.uid == uid"
        ".write": "request.auth.uid == uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then these rules restrict access to the authenticated owner of the content only. The data is only readable and writable by one user, and the data path contains the user's ID.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access